# Creating Generic Component -Angular2

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, angular-forms

I wish to create a generic component, which accepts array of object (eg : Person, Address) and corresponding template for mapping that (supposably card template), which is editable ie. once i click on card i get modalpopup with respective model properties which i can edit and are reflected back in the list of cards.

Till now what i have achieved is, 
I created CardList component, which takes array object and corresponding template as a input, displays the cards as expected.

my demo code link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mwyjic

so on click of edit i get corresponding object, so which i can update.

So what i desire to achieve is:
1. I should be able recognize the current object type in popup(ie person or address)
2. I should be able populate modal structure according to current model  [Any Possible approach or  can we  take template as a reference for modal?or we how we can take modal template as a input. or i need to use reative form to construct reactive form? ] Need suggestion on this part.
3. Update the item current object in modal and reflect changes in cards.

Any suggestions on how can proceed further?

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to extract object properties without knowing the type? Then I suggest you look into Typescript (or better yet, Javascript) **reflection**.

Lets say you have a class `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
class Foo {
    private fooPropA: string = null;
    public fooPropB: string = null;
}

class Bar {
    private barPropA: number= null;
    public barPropB: number = null;
}
```

Please notice they have to be defined as well as declared for this to work. It has to do with how typescript is compiled to javascript - compiled javascript class wont have needed properties if you don't define them in typescript.

Then you can get and interact with properties like this:

```
someMethod() {
    let foo: Foo = new Foo();
    foo.fooPropA = "Hello";
    foo.fooPropB = "World";

    let bar: Bar= new Bar();
    bar.barPropA = 1;
    bar.barPropB = 2;

    this.logObject(foo);
    this.logObject(bar);
}

logObject(obj: any) {
    // field will not be listed in keys if it's declared, but not defined
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);

    for (const key of keys) {
        console.log("key", key);

        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log("value", obj[key]);
            console.log("value type is:", typeof obj[key]);

            if(typeof obj[key] === "string") {
                obj[key] = "EDITED";
            }

            if(typeof obj[key] === "number") {
                obj[key] = 123;
            }

            console.log("new value:", obj[key]);
        } else {
            console.log("no prop found:", key);
        }
    }
}
```